# Regex pattern match only the first two times

Tags: javascript, regex

**General question**

How do you prevent a regex match if that pattern has been matched N number of times previously?

**Specific example**

I have a 13 digit record identifier the user will type into a text field, such as "123-456-7891011".

The behavior I'm attempting to encapsulate is to add a dash before the 4th and 7th digits as they are typed. I have all the javascript around handling the event with no issues.

It will always be numeric - I handle that before this particular step.

I'm able to get the regex down well enough to insert the dash when I type the n+4th digit every time. What I need is for it to not do that any time after the second "-"

The closest I have in my event handler (`oninput`) so far is:

```
var addDash = /([^\-\d{3}]*\d{3})(\d+)/;
this.value = this.value.replace(addDash, "$1-$2");
```

For example, typing "1234567891011" results in "123-456-789-101-1", where what I want is "123-456-7891011".

There are probably *other ways* to handle this situation (like `split` and `join`) but for purposes of **this question** let's stick to answering with correct regex pattern, if such a pattern is possible. There are other things happening that would make having this pattern very useful - I just haven't had luck fathoming it out.

---

**For clarity**, this pattern will be run `oninput` on the text field - the match should work for any length of characters between 1 and 13:

```
"123456" -> "123-456"
"123456789" -> "123-456-789"
"1234567891011" -> 123-456-7891011"
```

Comment: @anubhava that only works for the full length pattern, not every situation. I updated the OP for clarity

Comment: You mean any length of text 1 - 15. Are you processing onkeypres, or on every keyboard input, even backspace or arrow's? Are you processing _paste_ ?

Comment: You regular expression doesn't do what you think it does already. `[^-\d{3}]*` means 0 or more characters that are not hyphen, a digit, a left brace, a digit 3 or a right brace. So excludes all valid characters, so it will always be zero characters matched.

Comment: `For example, typing "1234567891011"` do you get `123` before `1234567` ...?

Comment: If you run a rewrite of the text box on every key entry, it will look jerky unless it's a composite (i.e. double buffered). Better to process/rewrite only when there is a change. In other words, let the box handle adding, then rewrite when deleting. or appending a `-`. Maintain a last current image to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex without additional JS:

```
var addDash = /^((\d{3}\-?)(\d{3}\-?)?)(\d)$|^(\d{3})(\d)$/;
this.value = this.value.replace(addDash, "$1$5-$4$6");
```

Starting as the beginning of the string, match 3 digits with an optional "-", and optionally 3 more digits, followed immediately by a final digit at the end of the string. If that doesn't match, see if the string starts with 3 digits followed immediately by a final digit at the end of the string.

Get a little funky with the capture groups in the replace string to accomplish the desired format.

Answer (score 3):

Use [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

> You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement string.

A solution specific to your current need would be to alter the pattern and always go for a full match:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d{3})-?(\d{3})?-?(\d*)$/, function (m, a, b, c) {
    return b ? a + "-" + b + "-" + c : a + "-" + c;
});
```

Job done.

If you want a more generic solution, you could use a counter variable:

```
var count = 0;
this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})-?/g, function (m, a) {
    return ++count <= 2 ? a + "-" : m;
});
```

This one uses a pattern that is less accurate for what you need, but it's there to demonstrate how you could generalize to different situations where you *really* need to limit the number of replacements.

---

By the way, you have a syntax misunderstanding: `[^\-\d{3}]` does **not** mean what you think. It will match a *single* character that is not a digit or either of those: `-`, `{` or `}`. Everything inside `[`...`]` brackets defines a *character class*, therefore quantifiers such as `{n}` are meaningless there.

Comment: I think your second example will keep adding hyphens to the first 3 digits.

Comment: @NetMage it won't, as the pattern matches an optional hyphen if it follows the group of 3 digits. If it's there, it will be "replaced".

Comment: I see what you mean - `a` only includes the parenthesized match.

Comment: +1 for the solution, it's good information and helped lead me to the answer I was looking for. I cannot accept as the final answer though as I specifically asked for the regex pattern solution. Thanks!

Comment: @RandyHall well, that's totally a regex solution if you ask me, but do as you wish, happy it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback within replace with some logic on how to handle the delimiters. This will make it easier to get the behavior you are expecting.

```js
var values = ['12', '123', '123-4', '123-45', '123-456', '123-456-7', '123-456-7891011'];
var addDash = /^(\d{3})-?(\d?\d?\d?)-?(\d*)/;
values.forEach(function(value) {
  value = value.replace(addDash, function(match, capture1, capture2, capture3) {
    var secondDelimiter = capture2.length == 3 ? '-' : '';
    return capture1 + '-' + capture2 + secondDelimiter + capture3;
  });

})
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(function() {
    var txt='1232';
    var addDash = /^(\d{3})-?(\d?\d?\d?)-?(\d*)/;
    $("#test").html(txt.replace(addDash, function(match, capture1, capture2, capture3) {
        var firstDelimiter = (capture1.length == 3 && capture2.length > 0) ? '-' : '';
        var secondDelimiter = (capture2.length == 3 && capture3.length > 0) ? '-' : '';
        return capture1 + firstDelimiter + capture2 + secondDelimiter + capture3;
    }));
})
```